# Which JAR file in JRE library does java.lang.* reside in ? If I want to search for a specific class file?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Under Project It shows JRE Library and a list of JAR files having many class files. I want to Know how to search for java.lang.Object class for example?

Comment: Why do you need the class file? You can see all the sources at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/). Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: GrepCode is good for checking some odd classes. It's way too slow to use for something you do dozens of times a day.

Comment: @Kayaman do you look at the source of a library class dozens of times a day (as opposed to looking at the API)?

Comment: I want to rewrite Object class to make it more flexible and meet my requirements. So in order doing that I wanted to see the class file @RealSkeptic

Comment: What are your requirements that you need to rewrite Object?

Comment: getClass() returns a type for example Java.lang.String.For now I want to write an extra method of gettype() to parse to get it's exact type and later on may be more functions flexible for my project @DaveNewton

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, because then I can see both the Javadoc *and* the sourcecode. It's also a lot easier to have access straight from the IDE to the standard classes, as well as maven dependencies. Going to grepcode every time would be a lot more time consuming.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand; what are you considering to be the difference between an object's class and its type? And what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You realize that you can't replace the `Object` class, don't you?

Comment: I have a scenario Where in I have been passed an Object array. This array has Strings, integers and so on.... I just wanted to know the type of each object(using getclass() function) to make a Prepare statement for writing into Mysql database. So I wanted to write a seperate Object Class file and use that. So in this file I want an extra method of getType() which returns String or Integer or whatever It may be @DaveNewton

Comment: I am not replacing the object file. Just wanted to use my own flexible file @RealSkeptic

Comment: However, that can't be done. You can't declare your own `java.lang.Object` - your JVM will throw a security exception.

Comment: I still don't get it. You know what type they are already.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the clarity. I wanted to extend the class Object to write my own Object class with some extra methods.

Comment: Right, and I'm asking why. Knowing why allows advice to be given that may solve your problem. You already know the type--this is how the countless libraries that use reflection solve the problem you've described. Plus unless you hack the VM, as already stated, you can't replace internals like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press ctrl+shift+T and search for `Object`. Then click the "Link to editor" button on the left in project explorer. If you've set things up correctly (i.e. linked rt.jar with src.zip, although I'm not sure if you need to do this explicitly anymore) you'll see both the source code for `Object` and see that it exists in rt.jar.

Comment: I assume you are implicitly using Eclipse IDE for this ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer You don't need to assume anything. The question explicitly talks about Eclipse. It even has the `eclipse` tag.

Comment: sorry, my bad ;)

Answer (score 4):

The package `java.lang` is located in the `rt.jar` of the jvm

Answer (score 0):

You may find a .java file, but it is not sure you can find a Java implementation.

I bet that the underlying code is java byte code or native code.

See for instance this :

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Object.java