# Where are the java. packages such as java.lang and java.util located?

Tags: java

Are these packages in some directory called java? I have not been able to find any package called java though in my IDE. Where would these packages java.lang or java.util be located at? If it is located in the JRE or JDK, is the word "java" inside java.lang representing the directory/package where the JDK is located at? The reason I ask is because typically such syntax is used for packages.

Comment: In the Java JDK source code. For example, [`java.lang.String`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

Comment: What IDE do you use? Regardless, you should be able to see the JDK's code in your IDE, it can be useful sometimes, so I recommend you to do it, and same for all libraries you use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which JAR file in JRE library does java.lang.\* reside in ? If I want to search for a specific class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927233/which-jar-file-in-jre-library-does-java-lang-reside-in-if-i-want-to-search-f)

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE. So does the word "java" inside java.lang represent the java JDK source code directory or package?

Comment: Note that compared to the linked duplicate, things changed a little bit with Java 9 and higher, they now live in jmod files, instead of rt.jar.